# Vault of Glass Praetorian Foil?

Tags: destiny

Is the Vault of Glass Templar drop Praetorian Foil fusion rifle *the* rarest gun in the game? I had one and dismantled it because I didn't know what ascension was at the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there really isn't a rarest gun in the game.  That is to say, there are no known (official) drop percentages for any of the weapons.

Praetorian foil is a pretty rare drop though, as are most of the hard mode VoG weapons(Praetorian Foil, Praedyth's Timepiece, Fatebringer, Corrective Measure).  This is purely anecdotal, as my own experience.

Comment: However, I do think that the Praetorian Foil is rarer than normal, because I've only seen it drop twice in the middle of countless Fatebringers.

Comment: That's just your experience though, I would say I've seen Praedyth's Timepiece drop the least, and I ran VoG HM 3x a week from the first week it was available up until sometime in early April.  You'll get another eventually.

Answer (score 1):

The Necrochasm is *the* rarest weapon in the game because of the very low drop rate of the Crux of Crota in order to upgrade from Eidolon Ally.

There have been no notices about the drop rate of the Praetorian Foil, and as such it must share the same rate as other legendaries in the Vault of Glass. Don't worry about dismantling it, you can easily obtain another by running a few weeks of Vault of Glass.